# How can I write a function that returns a list of keys in a nested table?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, recursion, lua

I have a hierarchically nested associative array. It looks like this:

```
A = { 
    B = { 
        C = {}, 
        D = {}, 
    }, 
    E = { 
        F = { 
            G = {} 
        } 
    }, 
    H = {} 
}
```

I would like to write a function that returns the "ancestors" of each key.

So:

```
f("A") = {"A"} 
f("B") = {"B","A"} 
f("C") = {"C","B","A"} 
f("G") = {"G","F","E","A"} 
f("fake") = {}
```

I've worked out I need to use recursion, but I'm having difficulty writing the function. Could someone give me some pointers on how to write such a function?

(Please don't refer me to http://xkcd.com/138/!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just apply a recursive [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find your specific element and return the path.

Recursive steps to construct path for element `X`.

- If current element is `X`: return `{X}`
- If current element is not `X`:

  1. Check all child nodes.
  2. Get the child-node that returns a valid path and add current element to it.
  3. If there is no valid child-node, return `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the method I should use. I've got it working nicely now.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = {
    B = {
        C = {},
        D = {},
    },
    E = {
        F = {
            G = {}
        }
    },
    H = {}
}

function f(root, find)
    -- iterate over all child values
    for k, v in pairs(root) do
        if k == find then
            -- found the match
            return({find})
        else
            -- no match, search the children
            tmp = f(root[k], find)
            if tmp ~= nil then
                table.insert(tmp, 1, k)
                return tmp
            end
        end
    end
end

print(table.concat(f(A, "G"), " "))
```

since you cannot retrieve the name of the highest-order table (in this case, A), you might need to nest this table into another table as in the following example:

```
r = {A = {
    B = {
        C = {},
        D = {},
    },
    E = {
        F = {
            G = {}
        }
    },
    H = {}
}
}
```

in this case, you will need to call f(r, "G"), of cause.

Comment: Good point about the outer table.
That's pretty much the solution I came up with, except mine returns `{}` rather than `nil`. Also, you can scrap the `if k == find` and add a `if root[key] ~= nil` at the very beginning

Answer (score 1):

If there are loops in the hierarchy, you'll need to keep track of visited subtables.
See the [globals code](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo?globals) in the [Lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with with using Dario's advice:

```
function checkTable(t, key)
    if t[key] then
        return {key}
    else
        for k, subtable in pairs(t) do
            local children = checkTable(subtable,key)
            if #children ~= 0 then
                table.insert(children,1,k)
                return children
            end
        end
        return {}
    end
end
```